# Calling Convention with a shared library for android

Tags: android, c++, arm, calling-convention, stdcall

I created some plugin files in C++ for my Unity3d app. So far the app was just a simple protype, so I tested only on my desktop with libraries compiled as DLL for Windows. Today I recompiled those files as .so(Shared Object) for Android(both arm and x86) and got a warning message.

> warning : calling convention '__stdcall' ignored for this target
>   [-Wignored-attributes]

**1. This means all functions are compiled as __cdecl?**

**2. Can't I specify the calling convention in .so library?**

I replaced __stdcall with __cdecl, but it also occurs a warning message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of these are non-standard historical Microsoft baggage for IA32 (they are in fact non-portable, standards compliant extensions to C and C++, implemented by Microsoft's compilers and by GCC for interoperability), for which the *NIX world has - and never had a need.

On just about all ARM systems you'll ever encounter (and all Android ones), the calling convention is dictated by the [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf). Not surprisingly, there is no equivalent for ARM as there is no need for them.

Your best course of action is to use empty macros to make them go away.

```
#define __cdecl
#define __stdcall
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your very informative answer! I didn't know that. But to be honest, I got more confused now.. I can remove all the calling conventions from C++ source files, that's not a big deal. But problem is in C# sources. I'm using [DllImport] attribute in order to import my unmanaged library in C#. The default calling convention of [DllImport] is StdCall. That's why I asked the first question, so that I could match them. Do you think it is okay not to set any calling conventions in C#? I'll accept your answer first

Comment: You'll still need them on Windows (I imagine they have no effect for IA64).   You'll need to define these macros when compiling for anything but IA32/x86 on Windows.

Comment: okay, I'll leave them using the macros as you said. But what I wanted to know was how to deal with C# for android.. As default setting, [DllImport("myDLL")] means [DllImport("myDLL", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]. I thought this might cause errors in certain situations.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I strongly suspect that the bindings on Android won't care: There's only ever one calling convention in use.   If, for some reason it complains about their absence, arrange that your macros apply only when you build the library with a non-microsoft compiler.